# PDOException on mysql DB: 'There is already an active transaction' when parallel testing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

- Laravel Version: 8.33.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.3
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7.32

#### Description:

Greetings, we want to test multiple database interactions, so we need isolated tests and a way to create / migrate / seed replicas of our mysql database (disk storage). We are using Sanctum for authentication.

I've been trying to use the new parallel testing functionality and read your different docs and issues about it.

My conclusions are:

- the DatabaseTransactions trait is needed, the others are "replaced" in whole or in part by ParallelTesting
- the new ParallelTesting::setUpTestDatabase() is exactly what I need to seed the databases at creation
- no test db definition required as ParallelTesting will already create copies of the form name_test_1, name_test_2
- without --recreate-databases, seeding won't be called again as it is only called after its test db is created

My seeds are a bunch of factories, DB::unprepared.

Running `art migrate:fresh` and `art db:seed` manually then `art test` without `--parallel`, tests work fine. However when running with `--parallel --recreate-databases`, the seeding does not work and I stumble upon this error:

> PDOException: There is already an active transaction

```
EE                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:14.187, Memory: 20.00 MB

There were 2 errors:

1) Tests\Feature\AuthTest::testAuthLogin
PDOException: There is already an active transaction

[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:137
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:113
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseTransactions.php:21
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:129
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:90

2) Tests\Feature\AuthTest::testAuthGetUser
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`company_id`, [cut]))

[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:638
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:472
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:424
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php:32
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2882
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1547
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1052
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1017
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:858
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:275
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:234
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:278
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:236
[root]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:230
[root]/tests/Feature/AuthTest.php:73

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 2.
```

Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\ParallelTesting;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Executed when a test database is created...
        ParallelTesting::setUpTestDatabase(function () {
            Artisan::call('db:seed');
        });
    }
}
```

tests/CreatesApplication.php

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

tests/TestCase.php

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

migrations/*.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ImportDbTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(base_path().'/database/dump.sql'));
    }
}
```

phpunit.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Example test

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAuthLogin()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'test@login.com',
            'password' => 'test_1',
        ]);

        $response = $this->postJson('/auth/login', [
            'email' => 'test@login.com',
            'password' => 'test_1',
            'device_name' => 'test_1'
        ]);

        $response->assertOk()->assertJsonFragment([
            'status' => 'Success',
            'message' => null
        ]);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('data', $response);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('token', $response['data']);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!